# Webpack and object properties

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

I'm trying to put a webpack (4) combined javascript into an application that uses Rhino for embedded javascript, and I'm having a problem.

My generated javascript has objects with properties called `delete`:

```
var x = {
  delete: function(arg){/* ... */}
}
```

Now, this is legal in Javascript, but when I try to use my generated code in the Rhino app I get an error here:

```
x.delete(myVal);
```

> > missing name after . operator

If I do this, it works -> `x['delete'](myVal);`

I cannot modify the app I'm using this code in, so how can I make webpack generate the accessor using `[]` instead of `.` for object properties?

Comment: I wonder if you're in strict mode and if that might be causing the issue

Comment: `delete` is a keyword in JavaScript, try to avoid using `delete` as the property name

Comment: @kit - It's allowed, and I'm using lots of libraries so that's not really a useful suggestion

Comment: It's not use strict, I removed all of those